# Preventing camera capture images in gallery

Tags: android, sqlite, camera, android-sqlite, gallery

How to prevent android camera capture images appear in gallery or not be stored any where on device.Im using sqlite db to store images where i have no problem.But i want the captured images not be displayed or otherwise not be saved on device.

Comment: do not use built in camera app then your image will not stored in gallery

Comment: then i need to create a plugable custom camera with in my app and access it.is it right??? @AbhishekSingh Singh

Comment: either build a custom camera using surface view or delete the captured images in `onActivityResult(int request, int result, Intent date) {}`

Comment: yes @chandra_androids. use custom camera

Comment: either you can follow kishna147 answer given below..

Answer (score 2):

You can put your own logic into the handler that is called whenever you capture an image from the camera:

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {    
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
          // Get the File path here
          // write your code for pushing the file in Sqlite
         // Delete The File from gallery by using filepath
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you open camera from your app you can do that but user open camera from other app or default camera app you cant able to do that

Just dont do anything here

```
  @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);      
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_FILE_CAPTURE:

                break;         
           default:

                break;
        }
    }
```